# type 'MappedListIterable<String, Widget>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this where I want to display every element from this list of Iterable in their very own container respectively and wrap them so they spread evenly on the screen but it is giving me the error Iterable<Widget, String> is not a subtype of List. I even converted it to list before mapping it. Can anybody help

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Time extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TimeState createState() => _TimeState();
}

class _TimeState extends State<Time> {
  String time = "Press Button to see time";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TimeOfDay startTime = TimeOfDay(hour: 01, minute: 00);
    final endTime = TimeOfDay(hour: 23, minute: 59);
    final step = Duration(minutes: 5);

    Iterable<TimeOfDay> getTimes(
        TimeOfDay startTime, TimeOfDay endTime, Duration step) sync* {
      var hour = startTime.hour;
      var minute = startTime.minute;

      do {
        yield TimeOfDay(hour: hour, minute: minute);
        minute += step.inMinutes;
        while (minute >= 60) {
          minute -= 60;
          hour++;
        }
      } while (hour < endTime.hour ||
          (hour == endTime.hour && minute <= endTime.minute));
    }

    final times = getTimes(startTime, endTime, step)
        .map((tod) => tod.format(context))
        .toList();

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Wrap(
          direction: Axis.horizontal,
          children: times.map<Widget>(
            (t) => Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.deepOrange,
                  width: 1,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                  10.0,
                ),
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Text(t),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The debug console shows this

[image]

Comment: Can you point which line is this giving the error? You could show the exact error you are getting

Comment: @Sisir I added the debug console image

Comment: @Sisir I got the solution. Thanks for trying :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add .toList() function like this

```
return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Wrap(
      direction: Axis.horizontal,
      children: times
          .map<Widget>(
            (t) => Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.deepOrange,
                  width: 1,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                  10.0,
                ),
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Text(t),
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Never mind worked just fine. Thank You I'm accepting your answer Once again Thank You.